# JIRA desktop app

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Does anyone know of any good desktop [applications](/questions/tagged/applications) for Atlassian JIRA, preferably free/open-source?

---

#### Possible solutions I found:

> ### [Majic](http://erikhinterbichler.com/apps/majic/)
>
> It is no longer maintained by the developer, I tried to run it anyway and it threw an NSURL error when I attempted to login with it so I'm assuming it doesn't work anymore..

---

> ### [Bee](http://www.neat.io/bee/jira-client.html)
>
> Looks good, and may go with this but it's $29 per license and I'd prefer something free, [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) would be ideal.

---

> ### [JiraPal](https://github.com/wronco/JIRA-Pal)
>
> An open source app I found on Github that looked very promising but is apparently no longer maintained.  I was able to successfully build it but was not able to successfully connect it to my Jira site. :(

---

> ### [Jirasic](https://github.com/ralcr/Jirassic)
>
> Discovered this from a posted answer below.  Looks awesome but have not beenable to build it successfully at all.  :(

---

#### Notes:

A free &/or open-source solution would be preferable and it must work w/ OSX [yosemite](/questions/tagged/yosemite) as a native desktop app or notification bar/widget of some sort.  Dependencies, including Java, would be fine, but I always prefer things to be lightweight and containable without having to run Java, a browser, or any host applications/dependency services.

Comment: I tried [Majic](http://erikhinterbichler.com/apps/majic/) and it connected OK for me on MacOS 10.13.4  (once I guessed the right URL). The website says *"no longer under development and may or may not work for you"*, and it doesn't seem to be open source, so that's a shame.

Answer (score 4):

We used jira for a while and I just loaded it into a fluid instance.

http://fluidapp.com

It is an app that lets you isolate a website into its own browser.

Comment: Tried to do this just now but their auth uses a new window redirect that makes the login process go off the rails every time.

Comment: Maybe questionable value in commenting five years later, but I had this problem and fixed it by going into Preferences for the Fluid app and setting "Whitelist" to "Allow browsing to any URL". Then the single-sign-on flow worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also amazed that so little alternatives exist for this. My problem is tracking the time, not the issues boards, so i'm building a plain simple tool for that. The way it works is when you finish a task you open the app from the status bar and write some details of what you've done, and that's all. You will have this list synced on your iphone so you can read them next day in the scrum meeting. When you feel like you can transfer the tasks to jira timesheet but i'm working on automating this. Take it from here, might not be free forever https://github.com/ralcr/Jira-Logger

Comment: This looks amazing but how do I build it?  I tried opening the xcodeproj and running it as is but get a bunch of Switch compiler errors.  Thx.

Comment: I concur that it's great work.  iOS + Mac UI + Mac Terminal app, nicely done.  I got it working from GitHub, but will probably pay for it next version when you charge.

Comment: Thanks, i'm doing some hard work for the next release, i'll have IAP for 2 features, reading git logs and saving to jira tempo. You can check the git_logs branch.

Answer (score 1):

I would give Fluid app a vote instead. 
I personally tried Bee, doesn't meet my requirements and it looks pretty incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

[Jira now has a Jira Cloud for Mac app](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-software/jira-cloud-app-for-mac).

EDIT - [Jira *had* a Mac app](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Mobile-Apps-articles/Announcement-Sunsetting-the-Jira-Cloud-for-Mac-App/ba-p/1911778).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly lightweight, but it's free (and the underlying technology is open source): Atlassian Eclipse Connector

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/IDEPLUGIN/Installing+the+Eclipse+Connector

If you're already using Eclipse, it would fit in nicely with your existing setup.

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse.  But since you mentioned it, I'm going to check out the similar plugin for PHPStorm.

Answer (score -1):

I use the jira in webstorm. You can try it.